# Weblogic 12.1.3 Configuration for compression gzip

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, gzip, servlet-filters

My project is deployed in *weblogic 12 c*. It has multiple web projects including a *spring mvc web project* intended for restful services. Can I have any solution in *weblogic* domain wide web application configuration to provide *gZip* compression enabled?

I tried to follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72987_01/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/web_applications/ConfigureGZIPCompression.html).

But I'm unable to find any field to put values in GZIP Compression Enabled,
GZIP Compression Min. Content Length,
GZIP Compression Content Type option.

Answer (score 0):

the GZIP option is available only from weblogic 12.2.1
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES107